# Distance between subsets of metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Consider a metric space $(X, d)$ and $A \subset X$ and $K \subset X $. Suppose $K$ is compact. Consider $d(A, K) = \inf_{a \in A, k \in K} d(a, k)$

There exist sequences $(a_n \in A)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(k_n \in K)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $d(a_n, k_n) \to \inf_{a \in A, k \in K} d(a, k) $. Since $K$ is compact, it is closed so that $k_n \to k_0 \in K$. Then

$$d(a_n, k_0) \to \inf_{a \in A, k \in K} d(a, k).$$

Does this imply $\inf_{a \in A, k \in K} d(a, k) = \inf_{a \in A} d(a, k_0)$? If so, how?

Comment: Simply from the fact that $K$ is compact you cannot deduce that $(k_n)_{\mathbb N}$ converges, only that it has a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "no", and counterexamples abound.

- Let $A = (-\infty, -2) \cup (2, \infty)$ and $K = \{\pm 1\}$.  Observe that $d(A,K) = 1$.  For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define
  $$ a_n := (-1)^n \left( 2 + \frac{1}{n} \right), \qquad k_n = (-1)^n. $$
  We have $d(a_n,k_n) \to 1$, as desired, but $(k_n)$ is not a convergent sequence.
- Let
  $$ A = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : d(z,0) = |z| < 1 \}, \quad\text{and}\qquad
  K = \{ x \in \mathbb{C} : d(z,0) = |z| = 1\}. $$
  Here, $d(A,K) = 0$.  Define
  $$ a_n = \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right) \exp(in), \qquad\text{and}\qquad
  k_n = \exp(in).
  $$
  Then
  $$ d(a_n, k_n)
  = \left| a_n - k_n \right|
  = \left| \frac{1}{n} \exp(in) \right|
  = \frac{1}{n}
  \to 0
  = d(A,K). $$
  Again, $(k_n)$ is not convergent.  Indeed, $(k_n)$ is not even periodic—we have $k_m \ne k_m$ for all natural numbers $m$ and $n$.

In order to play the game that is played in the question, we should think along slightly different lines.  The goal, it seems, is to find a point $k_0 \in K$ such that
$$ d(A,K) = \inf_{a\in A} d(a,k_0). $$
By definition of the infimum, if
$$ D = d(A,K) = \inf_{(a,k)\in A\times K} d(a,k), $$
there is a sequence $( (a_n,k_n) )_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $ d(a_n, k_n) = D$.  Because $K$ is a *compact* subset of our metric space $(X,d)$, it has the Bolzano-Weirstrass property, i.e. every sequence in $K$ has a convergent subsequence.  Let $(k_{n_j})_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ be this subsequence, and suppose that $k_{n_j} = k_0$.  Then
$$ D
= \lim_{j\to \infty} d(a_{n_j}, k_{n_j})
= \lim_{j\to \infty} d(a_{n_j}, k_0)
= \inf_{a\in A} d(a,k_0)
\ge \inf_{(a,k)\in A\times K} d(a,k)
= d(A,K)
= D.
$$
I am sweeping some details under the rug, so check that you understand each equality and inequality above.  In any event, the important bit is that we have $D$ on both sides, so the inequality must be an equality.  Therefore
$$ d(A,K) = \inf_{a\in A} d(a,k_0). $$
In other words, if $K$ is compact, then we can find a point $k_0 \in K$ such that $d(A,K) = \inf_{a\in A} d(a,k_0)$.  However, this point $k_0$ needn't be unique, and we have no guarantee that if $d(a_n,k_n) \to d(A,K)$ then $k_n \to k_0$.